# Retrieving the return value of a Python script

Tags: c#, python

I have an external C# program which executes a Python script using the `Process` class.

My script returns a numerical code and I want to retrieve it from my C# program. Is this possible?

The problem is, I'm getting the return code of `python.exe` instead of the code returned from my script. (For example, `3`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The interpreter does not return the value at the top of Python's stack, unless you do this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

or if you make a call to `sys.exit` elsewhere.

[Here's a lot more documentation on this issue.](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829)

Comment: 2.7.9 documentation for [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.exit#sys.exit).