# How to figure out the python script ran from C# has passed or failed

Tags: c#, process

I have the following code which calls Python application from C#,is there a way to figure out the python script ran from C# has passed or failed? Do we get any exit/return code indicating success or failure of the python applications ran from C#

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CallPython
{
        class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string python = @"C:\\Python27\python.exe";
            string myPythonApp = @"C:\\Dropbox\scripts\loadbuild\sum.py";
            int x = 2;
            int y = 5;

            ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(python);

            myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = myPythonApp + " " + x + " " + y;
            Process myProcess = new Process();
            myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
            myProcess.Start();
            StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;
            string myString = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            myProcess.WaitForExit();
            myProcess.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Value received from script: " + myString);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Return an `int` value from the python script, and capture it in your C# code.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1228550/102937) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides output a program writes to the its (standard) output channels, a program always terminates with an [exit status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) (or exit code). A program should exit with exit code `0` if it ran correctly and with an exit code other than `0` if it made some error.

Now a python program will usually exit with an exit status other than `0` when an arithmetic error is made, for instance the program:

```
a = 4/0
```

will not only produce an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.ply", line 1, in <module>
    a = 4/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

but also return with exit status `1`. Now evidently a python programmer can use `try`-`catch` handling such that the error does not result in an exit status other than zero, but that would - at least partly - defeat the use of the exit status.

If the programmer of the `python` program thus implemented the exit code when it errors correctly, or the error is an arithmetic one, the `python` program will exit with an exit code other than zero.

You can catch the exit code using [`Process.ExitCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode(v=vs.110).aspx).

In the documentation manual, we can read:

> Developers usually indicate a successful exit by an `ExitCode` value of zero, and designate errors by nonzero values that the calling method can use to identify the cause of an abnormal process termination. It is not necessary to follow these guidelines, but they are the convention.

For example:

```
//...
myProcess.WaitForExit();
int ec = myProcess.ExitCode;
if(ec != 0) {
    //oops the Python program made an error
} else {
    //assume everything went fine
}
```

Comment: Thanks Willem for the details,is there a way to get real time-output *and* at the same time pipe it to a variable  as in `string myString = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();`

Comment: what do you mean with *real-time output*?

Comment: Meaning,currently the stdout output the python script is printing is getting saved to variable myString and only after the python script finishes we can see the output...is there a way we can see the prints the python script is printing live *and* save to a variable for processing later on..